# "PUT" Method not allowed Error 405 with IIS Express 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

So I installed visual studio 2013 professional lately, and apparently it comes with IIS espress version 10 (or a preview of it), and when I try to do any kind of put request, I get a 405 error: "Method not allowed", but when I try with postman it works, so it must be a problem with IIS express. I looked at similar solutions and nothing has worked. All the WebDav stuff was already commented out in the applicationhost.config file, which it seems can interfere, and I already changed these lines to have "PUT" as a verb, and it didn't change anything. I also did the same thing in the project's web.config file and still 405 error.

```
add name="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />

add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />

add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

And I even came across the following:

```
verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
```

Which made me believe this shouldn't matter in the first place. And what's even stranger is DELETE works.

Comment: What does your method signature look like?

Comment: Which `applicationhost.config` file did you edit?

Comment: Method signature:         [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutAnnouncement(int title) and I changed ISS express' applicationhost.config, as well as trying that and in the project's web.config.